# Creating multiple independent keys for cascading - recommended approach?

Tags: encryption, keys

I would like to use cascading encryption with 3 algorithms in a similar fashion to Truecrypt, so for example:

```
Encrypted = AES( Twofish( Serpent(Secret, key1), key2), key3)
```

The aim of this is of course simple: if 1 algorithm is broken, the other(s) still provide security.

But what is the best approach to derive each key **independent** from each other, from the one passphrase? It was not obvious to me from TrueCrypt source how they did it, my websearches have failed, and understandably from that result it seems there are very few discussions so far on crypto stackexchange in regards to generating multiple independent keys.

I'm asking for suggestions, not making any recommendations, but in *Applied Cryptography* Bruce Schneier mentions how to derive an independent key that can be used to check if a key is valid, which if I'm understanding correctly is approximated as this:

```
KeyVerify  = Hash(password . salt)               // stored only for verifying but not used
RealKey    = Hash(KeyVerify . password . salt)   // actually used
```

Note: KeyVerify is independent from RealKey, but not vice versa

So I'm wondering if that approach might be of use, but I'm not confident how to extend it ... for example, something like this maybe?

```
RealKey2    = Hash(RealKey1 . password . salt) // for 2nd cipher
RealKey3    = Hash(RealKey2 . password . salt) // for 3rd cipher
```

Seeing as the KeyVerify/RealKey example shows a one-way line of independence, I'm guessing that the order the keys are used in is also a fundamental part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\concat}{\mathbin\Vert}$Use a key derivation function, such as HKDF, to expand a master password-derived key into subkeys for each cipher.

1. Compute $k = \operatorname{scrypt}(\mathit{password}, \dots)$.
2. Compute $k_\mathrm{AES} = \operatorname{HKDF}_k(\text{‘AES’})$.
3. Compute $k_\mathrm{Serpent} = \operatorname{HKDF}_k(\text{‘Serpent’})$.
4. Compute $k_\mathrm{Twofish} = \operatorname{HKDF}_k(\text{‘Twofish’})$.
5. Throw out *Applied Cryptography* and get *Cryptography Engineering* to replace it, but make sure to print out [the unauthorized errata](https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2013/07/22/applied-practical-cryptography/) and glue them into your copy of it.
6. Step back and write down a clear security model for your application, because higher-level logic in your application will be attacked long before the crypto.

Comment: Is this saying you would use HKDF on some short password "abc" then use the first 128 bits for the AES, the next 128 bits for Serpent, and the next 128 bits for twofish? These keys don't seem to be independent for short passwords, but maybe no scheme is.

Comment: More or less, except we go through scrypt first and use HKDF to expand the master secret into a longer one.  The only way to make them truly independent is to pick multiple passwords independently in the first place.

Comment: or maybe they become independent again in semantic terms once the password is more than 5 characters and has at least 1 numeric character, or something

Comment: ...Errr, no, that's not what independence means.

Comment: There would be some sized password with your scheme where the second key can't be worked out by a computationally bounded adversary that knows the first key.

Comment: and if not isn't this a bad answer to the question 'Creating multiple independent keys' I was just trying to suggest your answer could note the password length is a factor

Comment: More important than size is _entropy_.  That represents how uncertain the adversary is about what the password might be, and thus the expected number of guesses in the adversary's best strategy before they stumble upon the right one.  The parameters to scrypt determine a lower bound on the area\*time cost of each guess.  A sensible adversary won't bother trying to break HKDF; they'll try to guess the password, because that part is likely to have low entropy.

Comment: In the random oracle model, where HKDF is replaced by a function chosen uniformly at random, the keys are independent.  In the specific concrete case of HKDF-SHA256 or whatever, we use the standard crypto engineering approximation of treating them as independent even though they're technically not independent.